# How to use itertool product for arrays

Tags: python-3.x

I have two 2d-arrays, such as `array1` and `array2`. I want to repeat them,
for example `repeat = 2`, then I want to have output as:

> (array1, array1), (array1, array2), (array2, array1), (array2, array2)

How to do it?

Comment: Just pass your arrays as parameters to `itertools.product`. What did not work about that?
`result = list(itertools.product((array1, array2), (array1, array2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = list(itertools.product((array1, array2), (array1, array2)))
```